# How to use the function that expects RDD[(Double, Double)] as an input for a case of Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)]]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a variable of the type `Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)]]`:

```
val output: Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)]] = runStreams(ssc, numBatches, numBatches)
```

Now I want to apply the function `RegressionMetrics` that takes `RDD[(Double, Double)]` as an input:

```
val metrics = new RegressionMetrics(output)
```

How to transform `Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)]]` to RDD[(Double, Double)]` in order to be able to use functions of the class RegressionMetrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RDD` is Apache Spark's abstraction for a **Distributed Resilient Dataset**

To create an `RDD` you'll need an instance of `SparkContext`, which can be thought of as a "connection" or "handle" to a *cluster* running Apache Spark.

**Assuming**:

- You have an instantiated `SparkContext`
- You want to treat your input as a "flat" sequence of `(Double, Double)` values, *ignoring* the way these are currently "split" into sub-sequences in `Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)]]`

You can create an RDD as follows:

```
val sc: SparkContext = ???
val output: Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)]] = ???

val rdd: RDD[(Double, Double)] = sc.parallelize(output.flatten)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am using Seq for testing purposes. So, do I understand correctly, that in case of using some data stored on disk, I can read it into RDD and substitute Seq?

Comment: Correct! For testing - first, you can use Spark's local mode to easily create an independent SparkContext; Second, indeed you can either use `parallelize` as suggested here or load the data from the file directly via `SparkContext.textFile`